Dataclass inheritance variables not working
I have a dataclass subclass that is just inheriting variables. I know the keyword variables need to come last, but even with that, the order of variables in the subclass seems to have changed. I don't understand what the error message is telling me
@dataclass
class ZooAnimals():
  

    food_daily_kg: int
    price_food: float 
    area_required: float
    
    name: str = field(default='Zebra', kw_only=True)
   
    
c = ZooAnimals(565, 40, 10, name='Monkey')

Out: ZooAnimals(food_daily_kg=565, price_food=40, area_required=10, name='Monkey')

Now the subclass
@dataclass
class Cats(ZooAnimals):
    def __init__(self, food_daily_kg, price_food, area_required, name, meowing):
        meowing: str 
        super().__init__()


z = Cats(465, 30, 10, 'Little Bit', name='Leopard')

Out: TypeError: Cats.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'name'


ZooAnimals.__init__ still expects arguments when you write super().__init__; you just don't have to declare def __init__(self, food_daily_kg, price_food, area_required, *, name): ... explicitly.

See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for advice on using __init__ with super() correctly. (TL;DR: all the parameters should be keyword-only, though probably more relevant when you are writing __init__ yourself, rather than using a machine-generated method you don't have to maintain.)

Please try if the following code snippet works for you
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses import field

@dataclass
class ZooAnimals():
    food_daily_kg: int
    price_food: float 
    area_required: float
    name: str = field(default='Zebra', kw_only=True)

c = ZooAnimals(565, 40, 10, name='Monkey')

@dataclass
class Cats(ZooAnimals):
    meowing: str
    def __init__(self, meowing, food_daily_kg, price_food, area_required, name):
        self.meowing = meowing
        super().__init__(food_daily_kg, price_food, area_required, name=name)

z = Cats('Little Bit', 465, 30, 10, name='Leopard')


ZooAnimals class looks good
Cats class had issue with variable declaration and variable assignment for meawing.
Cats class had issue with variable ordering for meawing.


This works, but has a lot of unnecessary repetition.

This worked, thank you @Arjun Malik! Could you explain to me why the self.meowing=meowing needs to be, I thought when I defined meowing after the Cats class declaration, it was already initialized there. And also, what does the name=name in your second last line do?

@chepner what are the parts that are needlessly repetitive, besides not having to use the super in the first place, as was mentioned in the above comments too? I explained I am doing that because I want to understand how super function works

The entire explicit definition of __init__ is unnecessary. The dataclass decorator already knows how to generate an __init__ method that initializes both inherited and newly added attributes.

You don't need to use __init__() with dataclass when you are just adding attributes:
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
@dataclass
class ZooAnimals():
  
    food_daily_kg: int
    price_food: float 
    area_required: float
    
    name: str = field(default='Zebra', kw_only=True)

@dataclass
class Cats(ZooAnimals):
    meowing: str 


z = Cats(465, 30, 10, 'Little Bit', name='Leopard')

Output:
Cats(food_daily_kg=465, price_food=30, area_required=10, name='Leopard', meowing='Little Bit')


I understand, I did this to mainly get a better clue on how super() worked.

You are passing both 'Leopard' and 'Little Bit' as the parameter name. Python does not know what you are trying to do, and so throws an exception.
"Leopard" is passed as a keyword argument. "Little Bit" is passed as the 4th parameter in the call to Cats(...), which is the position of name in your custom __init__.
Are you expecting Python to skip over name, and pass 'Little Bit' as the value for meowing?
If you want to preserve name as a keyword-only argument, then you must mark it as such in the signature of Cats.__init__ eg.
def __init__(self, food_daily_kg, price_food, area_required, meowing, *, name):
    ...

However, you have a couple of other errors in your code. So it still won't quite work as you expect.  If you're just trying to add meowing the child dataclass Cats, then do:
@dataclass
class Cats(ZooAnimals):
    meowing: str 

Python will figure out the correct signature for Cats.__init__ automatically.
You can then do:
>>> Cats(0, 1, 2, 'meow', name='Leopard')
Cats(food_daily_kg=0, price_food=1, area_required=2, name='Leopard', meowing='meow')

It will also remember the default:
>>> Cats(465, 30, 10, 'meow')
Cats(food_daily_kg=465, price_food=30, area_required=10, name='Zebra', meowing='meow')


I would still want to understand how to map the variables, to get a better sense of the mechanics behind super(). Yes, I was expecting it to skip over name and pass 'Little Bit' to the meowing variable. Your advice on how to preserve kw-only arguments is helpful. However, when I ran the entire code with this one correction, it still threw me an error. Could you elaborate on the other errors I made, as you mention?
